# When I transfer to function parametr(id) in v-for cycle it passing the same id to every function. How to solve?

Tags: vue.js

I transfer `id` parameter into `submitOrder` function in `v-for` cycle and for every function call parameter (id) is the same.
I don't know what is the problem.

```html
<div v-for="order in orders">
    <button
        slot="agree_button"
        class="modal-submit-button"
        v-on:click="submitOrder(order.id)">
            DO THAT
    </button>
</div>
```

```js
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        //example of array orders
        orders: [
            0 : [id:0],
            1 : [id:1],
            2 : [id:2],
            3 : [id:3]
        ]
    }, 
    methods: {
        submitOrder: function (order_id) {
            var app = this
            console.log(order_id)   // Returns every time the same id=3
        }   
    }
})
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps you need to change your `orders` array to an object:

```data: {
    orders: {
      0 : {id:0},
      1 : {id:1},
      2 : {id:2},
      3 : {id:3}
    }
  }
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/crvfmdg2/2/

Comment: Yes, sorry, it is like this. But why it return the same id? If I just use it as text it returns normally 0 1 2 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue) or similar tools to share code; your data "orders" isn't valid.

Comment: Yes, I made a mistake it must be like: data: { orders: { 0 : {id:0}, 1 : {id:1}, 2 : {id:2}, 3 : {id:3} } }. But problem is the same

Comment: You have to use `data: { orders: [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}] }`

Answer (score 0):

Well, as it has already been said to you, your orders object in data is not correct.

But I don't know why you always get the same id in the console as I don't on my local test.

Here's the code I have for the template, that only fixes a little warning for `v-for` and its key:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="order in orders" :key="order.id">
      <button
        slot="agree_button"
        class="modal-submit-button"
        v-on:click="submitOrder(order.id)"
      >DO THAT</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Order",
  data: function() {
    return {
      orders: {
        0: { id: 0 },
        1: { id: 1 },
        2: { id: 2 },
        3: { id: 3 }
      }
    };
  },
  methods: {
    submitOrder: function(order_id) {
      // let vm = this;
      console.log("You hit the order n°" + order_id); // Returns every time the correct id
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

You can try [here](https://codesandbox.io/embed/vue-template-4ko1m)